# Requested feature is not implemented - JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken (RS256) using Xamarin on MAC

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I am building a MAC application using Xamarin. I run into an exception when I try to generate a JWT token using JwtSecurityTokenHandler and JwtSecurityToken. Specifically, I am using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(token) API which fails on MAC. The same API works fine on windows using Visual Studio 2012 (.NET framework 4.5).

WriteToken MSDN documentation:
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.writetoken(v=vs.114).aspx

The asymmetric key algorithm used is RSA-SHA256.

The MAC code fails with following exception:

Exception Details:

IDX10618: AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetHashAlgorithmForSignature( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256' ) threw an exception.
AsymmetricSecurityKey: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey'
SignatureAlgorithm: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256', check to make sure the SignatureAlgorithm is supported.
Exception: 'System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey.GetHashAlgorithmForSignature (System.String algorithm) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr3/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.3/mcs/class/System.IdentityModel/System.IdentityModel.Tokens/RsaSecurityKey.cs:58 
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSecurityKey key, System.String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures) [0x00101] in :0 '.

Has anyone used JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(token) API with RS256 on MAC using Xamarin?